# Best practice for multiple selection web UI?

Tags: user-interface, checkbox, selection

I've been looking at various ways to allow a user to select one or more choices from a list of approximately 29-30 options. I've come up with the following four types, and wonder which is preferred/most usable. See http://workingstorage.com/multiple%20selection.png

Comment: I think this is the wrong place for this question. There is no programming problem. Try superuser site.

Comment: It's a user experience question, a design question. Superuser isn't appropriate. Programming includes more than just pushing values onto stacks and pushing stuff to screens.

Comment: +1 to question for thinking about user design and fighting for it to remain part of the programming process!

Comment: Do you still have the linked image available?  This question (and answer) isn't complete without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would rank each option you have there, along with my reasoning:

**Best:** #2, if adjusted to break on year boundaries (i.e. always have a the full year in one column, so either have one year per column, or two, or whatever works out, but make sure that the user never has to move past the bottom of one column to find the next value for that year). This option will let users find the years they are interested in most quickly.

**Second:** #4. I'm tempted to put #3 here, because it seems more functional, but the illustration makes me wonder 1) if all the options are still available here and 2) if all users will understand what the four buttons do. Because of the confusion factor, I'm dropping #3 to last place. Which makes #4 second best, because it is cleaner than #1 (unless #1 happens to fit the rest of the design perfectly).

**Third:** #1 - by default.

**Fourth:** #3, save with the caveats presented above.